# Linux shell scripting: Using alias in a function

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell, alias

I use an **alias** named `ThousandsDotting` that add points `.` each 3 numbers (the classic dot for thousands), so `100000` become `100.000`.

It works fine in the shell, but **not in a function**.
Example file `example.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash 
function test() {
  echo "100000" | ThousandsDotting
}
alias ThousandsDotting="perl -pe 's/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3}){1,5}\b)/\1./g'"
test
```

If I run it, this is what I get:

```
$ ./example.sh
example.sh: line 3: ThousandsDotting: command not found.
```

What is the correct way to **pipe** (or use it without pipes, whatever) stdout data to this `perl` command in a function for my Bash shell script?

Comment: consider to accept a correct answer, this will help more people.@Sopalajo de Arrierez

Comment: By the way, @Bob.Z. But it will be good to give some more time to allow for more proposal and votes. My best answer for now is yours, but it would be good to hear about possible `shopt` consequences.

Comment: Reference wiki http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html @Sopalajo de Arrierez

Answer (score 3):

Alias is limited by default in bash, so just enable it.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    shopt -s expand_aliases
    alias ThousandsDotting="perl -pe 's/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3}){1,5}\b)/\1./g'"
    function test() {
      echo "100000" | ThousandsDotting
    }
    test
```

**output**

`100.000`

Comment: This answer is fine for me, but there will be no adverse consequences in enabling aliases expanding inside a script? I have checked my ~/.bashrc aliases, and there will be no collisions.

Comment: it is effective only in current shell session, in non-interactive shell it won't read aliases in ~/.basrc. just enjoy it:) @Sopalajo de Arrierez

Answer (score 2):

In BASH **Aliases are not inherited**.

Better you create a function instead:

```
ThousandsDotting() { perl -pe 's/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3}){1,5}\b)/\1./g' "$1"; }
```

You can then use it as **process substitution**:

```
ThousandsDotting <(echo "100000")
100.000
```

Comment: Should then be used this function as a pipe too?

Answer (score 1):

`alias` works in an interactive `bash`. Change

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```

From `man bash`:

```
If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.
```

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are not expanded in bash and can't be used as *macros*. You can enable them, and for more information look at the eternal guide to BASH http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html.

You can achieve the same as macros with the normal tools provided by bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
function test() {
    echo "100000" | perl -pe 's/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3}){1,5}\b)/\1./g'
}
test
```

You can improve this by making the function capable of having parameters: this way you can pass any argument to the function `test` obtaining exactly what you would have had by using an alias:

```
#!/bin/bash

function test() {
    perl -pe 's/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3}){1,5}\b)/\1./g' "$1"
}

test 100000
```